# How would I implement a User Control swapping method?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I'm trying to swap "Scenes", the equivalent of levels in a game. I already know that Forms is not good for gaming, but what I'm making isn't so much a game as it is an interactive movie built out of some dialog options and animated .gifs.

I plan on building each "Scene" in a separate User Control, and then load up those User Controls onto the main form with a separate script that handles all of the scenes. In this separate script, I was going to add the "ChangeScene" method, so I could essentially trigger a scene to change once it finished, and have all scene changes in one script. I've run into two problems so far.

1: I can't seem to call anything from this Scene Handler script. I've been trying to use "Form1.SuspendLayout" and "Form1.ResumeLayout" to swap between Scenes smoothly, but I can't seem to call that, and then when I try to set a boolean in a Scene to true once the scene finishes, I can't actually check that bool from the Scene Handler script. How can I let this one script use the bools from each of the Scenes?

2: Can I call the "Form1.SuspendLayout" method from this Scene Handler script? So far, I was told I needed a reference to 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.SuspendLayout()', although I don't know how to reference that. It's not a namespace or assembly, so how do I reference it?

Sorry if this question seems like a simple mistake. I'm new to Windows Forms and not too well experienced with C#, so any question I could find about this used terms too complicated for me to understand.

Scene Handler here: `class SceneHandler : 
    {
        public virtual UserControl changeScene(UserControl currentScene, UserControl newScene)
        {
            Form1.SuspendLayout();
            currentScene.Visible = false;
            currentScene.Dock = DockStyle.None;
            newScene.Visible = true;
            newScene.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            return newScene;  //use "this.SuspendLayout" and "ResumeLayout"
        }
    }`

Comment: `SuspendLayout` is the instance level method. If `Form1` isn't an instance (given as a parameter in either the `SceneHandler` constructor or the `changeScene` method itself) then you will gain a descriptive message : "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property System.Windows.Forms.Form.SuspendLayout()"

Comment: English please. This is exactly why I couldn't use any of the other questions about this. They're all a big mess of constructors, hierarchy and other terms that I don't know about. I don't understand what you're saying.

Comment: All these terms are actually very much English and it is a good idea to make yourself acquainted with them in a near future. What I say boils down to the fact that `changeScene` somehow needs to get the actual form instance (Form1 is just an abstraction that describes how actual instance(s) of it will look and behave). Basically change `changeScene` signature to `public virtual UserControl changeScene(UserControl currentScene, UserControl newScene, Form formInstance)` and the problematic line to `formInstance.SuspendLayout()`. As the third argument use `this` in the `Form1` method.

Comment: I get what you're saying now. When I say "English", I don't mean it in a literal way. I'm just asking for a more simplified explanation. Either way, you pulled through. Thanks for that. Although I can't give you best answer because it is a comment.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/) is something for you (too simple though if you're already fluent in some other class-based programming language).

Comment: @SassMaster I understand the pun, but that doesn't change the point - effective programming means good understanding of primary constructs, terms and principles related to the technologies you utilize. Without them it is very difficult to describe problems and understand solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Forget `SuspendLayout`.

Load all the UCs upfront but hidden.

Don't worry about performance before you run into problems!

Put all methods that involve more than one UC in the Form as public methods.

Put a public reference to your mainform in each UC and set it right after loading the UC.

Now each control can call `mainform.someMethod()`.

Feel free to ask for more advice and help!